# How to make element move when window is resized (bootstrap in use)?

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I have page here with 2 elements in it and bootstrap on the run, yet I fail to make the first element responsive.

1st element is a SVG with a path animation from Lazy Line Painter, it refuses to become responsive with the written code, doesn't move when the windows is being resized, I need help with it.

2nd Element is a heading which is responsive and looks great.

Question is: How do I get the first element to act like the second, thus being responsive instead of fixed (as it seems fixed when resizing the window)

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700'>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <title>The Code Home</title>
            <!--CSS Start-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
            <!--CSS End-->
            <!--Scripts Start-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.lazylinepainter-1.4.1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <!--Scripts End-->
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div id="pencilandbrackets"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div id="title" class="animated bounceInDown">The Code Home</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
    /*=======MAIN CSS=======*/

body { 
    background:#2ecc71;

}

#pencilandbrackets {
    position: absolute;
    top:-170px;
    left:200px;

    display: block;
}

#title {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4.13em;
    position: fixed;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -1.0em 0px 0px -3.2em;
    color: #2c3e50;
    display: block;
}

.lazy-line svg {
  width:300% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `@media` query with the max width that you'd like to hide this element at, then use `display: none;` on the element you wish to hide.

Comment: I have updated the question since I dind't explain clearly what I wanted.